# Parallelize two (or more) functions in julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to solve some wave equation problem (related to my Phd) using finite difference method. For this, I have translated (line by line) a fortran code (link below): (https://github.com/geodynamics/seismic_cpml/blob/master/seismic_CPML_2D_anisotropic.f90)
Inside these code and within the time loop, there are four main loops that are independent. In fact, I could arrange them into four functions. 
As I have to run this code about a hundred times, it would be nice to speed up the process. In this sense, I am turning my eyes toward parallelization. See below, as an example:

```
function main()

...some common code...
   for time=1:N
       function fun1() # I want this function to run parallel... 
       function fun2() # ..this function to run parallel with 1,3,4
       function fun3() # ..This function to run parallel with 2,3,4
       function fun4() # ..This function to run parallel with 1,2,3
   end
   ... more code here...
return
end
```

So,

1) Is it possible to do what I mention before?

2) Will this approach speed up my code?

3) Is there a better way to think this problem?

A minimal working example could be like this:

```
function fun1(t)
for i=1:1000
    for j=1:1000
        t+=(0.5)^t+(0.3)^(t-1);
    end
end
return t
end
```

```
function fun2(t)
for i=1:1000
    for j=1:1000
        t+=(0.5)^t;
    end
end
return t
end
```

```
function fun3(r)
for i=1:1000
    for j=1:1000
        r = (r + rand())/r;
    end
end
return r
end
```

```
function main()
    a = 2;
    b = 2.5;
    c = 3.0;
    for i=1:100
        a = fun1(a);
        b = fun2(b);
        c = fun3(c);
    end
return;
end
```

So, As can be seen, non of the three functions above (fun1, fun2 & fun3) depend from any ohter, so they can sure run parallel. can these be achieved?, will it bust  my computational speed?

Edited:

Hi @BogumiłKamiński  I have altered the finite-Diff-eq in order to implement a "loop" (as you sugested) over the inputs and outputs of my functions. If there is no much trouble, I would like your opinion over the parellelization design of the code:

Key elements
1) I have packed all inputs in 4 tuples: **sig_xy_in**  and **sig_xy_cros_in** (for the 2 sigma functions) and **vel_vx_in** and **vel_vy_in** (for 2 velocity functions). I then packed the 4 tuples into 2 vectors for "looping" purposes...
2) I packed the 4 functions in  2 vectors for "looping" purposes...
3) I run the first parallel loop and then unpack its output tuple...
4) I run the second parallel loop(for velocities) and then unpack its output tuple...
5) finally, I packed the outputed elements into the inputs tuples and continue the time loop until finish..

```
...code

  l = Threads.SpinLock()
  arg_in_sig  = [sig_xy_in,sig_xy_cros_in]; # Inputs tuples x sigma funct
  arg_in_vel  = [vel_vx_in,     vel_vy_in]; # Inputs tuples x velocity funct
  func_sig    = [sig_xy   ,   sig_xy_cros]; # Vector with two sigma functions
  func_vel    = [vel_vx   ,        vel_vy]; # Vector with two velocity functions

  for it = 1:NSTEP # time steps
    #------------------------------------------------------------
    # Compute sigma functions 
    #------------------------------------------------------------
    Threads.@threads for j in 1:2 # Star parallel of two sigma functs  
        Threads.lock(l);
        Threads.unlock(l);
        arg_in_sig[j] = func_sig[j](arg_in_sig[j]);
    end

    # Unpack tuples for sig_xy and sig_xy_cros
    # Unpack tuples for sig_xy
    sigxx    = arg_in_sig[1][1];  # changed by sig_xy
    sigyy    = arg_in_sig[1][2];  # changed by sig_xy
    m_dvx_dx = arg_in_sig[1][3];  # changed by sig_xy
    m_dvy_dy = arg_in_sig[1][4];  # changed by sig_xy
    vx       = arg_in_sig[1][5];  # unchanged by sig_xy
    vy       = arg_in_sig[1][6];  # unchanged by sig_xy
    delx_1   = arg_in_sig[1][7];  # unchanged by sig_xy
    dely_1   = arg_in_sig[1][8];  # unchanged by sig_xy

    ...more unpacking...

    # Unpack tuples for sig_xy_cros
    sigxy    = arg_in_sig[2][1];  # changed by sig_xy_cros
    m_dvy_dx = arg_in_sig[2][2];  # changed by sig_xy_cros
    m_dvx_dy = arg_in_sig[2][3];  # changed by sig_xy_cros
    vx       = arg_in_sig[2][4];  # unchanged by sig_xy_cros
    vy       = arg_in_sig[2][5];  # unchanged by sig_xy_cros

    ...more unpacking....

    #--------------------------------------------------------
    # velocity
    #--------------------------------------------------------
    Threads.@threads for j in 1:2 # Start parallel ot two velocity funct
       Threads.lock(l)
       Threads.unlock(l)
       arg_in_vel[j] = func_vel[j](arg_in_vel[j])
    end

    # Unpack tuples for vel_vx
    vx          = arg_in_vel[1][1];  # changed by vel_vx
    m_dsigxx_dx = arg_in_vel[1][2];  # changed by vel_vx
    m_dsigxy_dy = arg_in_vel[1][3];  # changed by vel_vx
    sigxx       = arg_in_vel[1][4];  # unchanged changed by vel_vx
    sigxy       = arg_in_vel[1][5];....

    # Unpack tuples for vel_vy
    vy          = arg_in_vel[2][1];  # changed changed by vel_vy
    m_dsigxy_dx = arg_in_vel[2][2];  # changed changed by vel_vy
    m_dsigyy_dy = arg_in_vel[2][3];  # changed changed by vel_vy
    sigxy       = arg_in_vel[2][4];  # unchanged changed by vel_vy
    sigyy       = arg_in_vel[2][5];  # unchanged changed by vel_vy
    .....

    ...more unpacking...

    # ensamble new input variables
      sig_xy_in  = (sigxx,sigyy,
              m_dvx_dx,m_dvy_dy,
              vx,vy,....);

      sig_xy_cros_in = (sigxy,
              m_dvy_dx,m_dvx_dy,
              vx,vy,....;

      vel_vx_in = (vx,....
      vel_vy_in = (vy,.....
end #time loop
```

Comment: From your description it is not clear if `fun1`, `fun2`, `fun3` and `fun4` share anything . If yes - you need multi-threading to have a fast code. If not - then multiprocessing is enough (but then each function executes on a separate process so data sharing will be slow). Both options are relatively easy to do in Julia. I would propose that it would be best if you copied some short (without algorithmic complexity) but runnable code that works on a single core - then it will be easier to give advice.

Comment: Do you want to do distributed or multithreaded computation? Check out [the parallelism documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/parallel-computing/index.html). You either want to spawn threads on Julia 1.3, or `Distributed.@spawnat`, depending on whether you want to use one node or many.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński So, I have edited the post with a minimal working example. There are now three functions that does not share any information. So, can I run each three functions parallel? will these parallelization enhance my speed convergence?. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Thanks for sharing the link to the manual. I am now reading this carefully. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: If you are sure you only read data then it is safe. You do not need `lock` in your code - it was only needed for printing (as IO is not thread safe until Julia 1.3). Apart from this the code looks correct (but it is probably a bit overly verbose, but this is another issue unrelated to threading).

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Thank you very much for your time!, I greatly appreciate your opinión!

Comment: If you have some other means of communication (e.g. Slack for Julia) I can send you hints how you could restructure your code. Just ping me there with your current code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple way to run your code in multithreading mode:

```
function fun1(t)
    for i=1:1000
        for j=1:1000
            t+=(0.5)^t+(0.3)^(t-1);
        end
    end
    return t
end
function fun2(t)
    for i=1:1000
        for j=1:1000
            t+=(0.5)^t;
        end
    end
    return t
end
function fun3(r)
    for i=1:1000
        for j=1:1000
            r = (r + rand())/r;
        end
    end
    return r
end

function main()
    l = Threads.SpinLock()
    a = [2.0, 2.5, 3.0]
    f = [fun1, fun2, fun3]
    Threads.@threads for i in 1:3
        for j in 1:4
            Threads.lock(l)
            println((thread=Threads.threadid(), iteration=j))
            Threads.unlock(l)
            a[i] = f[i](a[i])
        end
    end
    return a
end
```

I have added locking - just as an example how you can do it (in Julia 1.3 you would not have to do this as IO is thread safe there).
Also note that `rand()` is sharing data among threads prior to Julia 1.3 so it would be not safe to run these functions if all of them used `rand()` (again in Julia 1.3 it would be safe to do so).

To run this code first set the maximum number of threads you want to use e.g. like this on Windows: `set JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4` (in Linux you should `export`). Here is an example of this code run (I have reduced the number of iterations done in order to shorten the output):

```
julia> main()
(thread = 1, iteration = 1)
(thread = 3, iteration = 1)
(thread = 2, iteration = 1)
(thread = 3, iteration = 2)
(thread = 3, iteration = 3)
(thread = 3, iteration = 4)
(thread = 2, iteration = 2)
(thread = 1, iteration = 2)
(thread = 2, iteration = 3)
(thread = 2, iteration = 4)
(thread = 1, iteration = 3)
(thread = 1, iteration = 4)
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 21.40311930108456
 21.402807510451463
  1.219028489573526
```

Now one smal cautionary note - while it is relatively easy to make code multithreaded in Julia (and in Julia 1.3 it will be even simpler) you have to be careful when you do it as you have to take care of race conditions.

Comment: Thanks!. Now, when I try to run your code julia throws an error message saying: ERROR: LoadError: syntax: assignment not allowed inside tuple. Why can this be? I am using Julia 6.0

Comment: You should probably switch to Julia 1.2, but I think the code should run under 0.6. Please change the part `(thread=Threads.threadid(), iteration=j)` to `"thread ", Threads.threadid(), ", iteration ",j` as in Julia 0.6 `NamedTuples` were not yet available if I remember correct.y

Comment: with your implementation:                                                                             
julia > timev main()
14.460027 seconds (909 allocations: 14.516 KiB)
bytes allocated:   14864
                                                                                                                                      while with the previous:                                                                                                                  julia> timev main()
 22.390655 seconds (906 allocations: 14.438 KiB)
bytes allocated:   14784
Much faster. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no version 6.0. The latest stable version is 1.2, but in order to use the latest multithreading features you need the pre-release of version 1.3. I guess you are probably using version 0.6.

Comment: @DNF Indeed. I meant V0.6. My bad!

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński How can I know the maximum (or optimum) number of threads to use?. Is there an optimum number?. Do I have to use every thread available on my computer?... I am really blind regarding parallelization!

Comment: `Threads.@threads for i in 1:n` will use `min(n, Threads.nthreads())` threads. So - in general - you can tell Julia to use every thread available on your computer. Simply if `n` is small not all of them will be used.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Ok, but for what I understand from the code is that `n` can only take the value of 3, as there are 3 elements in vecor `a` or `f`. How can it take more than that?

Comment: In your problem you have a recursive relation `a = f(a)` so you will not speed up anything by using more than 3 threads (unless you are able to rewrite your algorithm so that it is possible to make more operations in parallel).

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Ok. But, the implementation of `Threads.@threads for i in 1:3` implies that I can organize my functions and I/O arguments in a vector form. This is not my case, as my functions take many many different arguments and outputs. Can I modify the code in order to avoid the `for` loop but still preserving the parallelization?

Comment: With threading this will be possible in Julia 1.3. With distributed computing - yes it will be possible also in Julia 1.2. I recommend you to refer to the documentation @Chris pointed you to, as the topic is too complex for comments on SO.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński I have edited my original post with some possible adaptation based on your suggestion. I would very much like (whenever you can) your insight on this approach! Bonus question: If there are two functions running in parallel that operates using the same matrices or data (but not changing them), can this be a problem?